# Not able to access Datastore Resources from GKE

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I  have  deployed  an  app in  GKE which  makes  a  backend  call  to  datastore to  perform  crud  operations.Added cloud  datastore  owner  role to  the  Service  account  on  which  gke  is  hosted.

when i  request  any  of  the  endpoint  which  makes  call  to  the  backend datastore  i  am  getting  below  excpetion:

```
com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: Unauthenticated. at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.translate(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:138) ~[google-cloud-datastore-1.105.0.jar:1.105.0] at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.translate(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:123) ~[google-cloud-datastore-1.105.0.jar:1.105.0] at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.lookup(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:173) ~[google-cloud-datastore-1.105.0.jar:1.105.0] at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$3.call(DatastoreImpl.java:416) ~[google-cloud-datastore-1.105.0.jar:1.105.0] at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$3.call(DatastoreImpl.java:413) ~[google-cloud-datastore-1.105.0.jar:1.105.0] at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:105) ~[gax-1.58.2.jar:1.58.2] at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76) ~[google-cloud-core-1.93.9.jar:1.93.9] at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50) ~[google-cloud-core-1.93.9.jar:1.93.9] at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.lookup(DatastoreImpl.java:412) ~[google-cloud-datastore-1.105.0.jar:1.105.0] at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$ResultsIterator.loadResults(DatastoreImpl.java:387) ~[google-cloud-datastore-1.105.0.jar:1.105.0] at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$ResultsIterator.<init>(DatastoreImpl.java:383) ~[google-cloud-datastore-1.105.0.jar:1.105.0] at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.get(DatastoreImpl.java:373) ~[google-cloud-datastore-1.105.0.jar:1.105.0] at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.get(DatastoreImpl.java:336) ~[google-cloud-datastore-1.105.0.jar:1.105.0] at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreHelper.fetch(DatastoreHelper.java:73) ~[google-cloud-datastore-1.105.0.jar:1.105.0] at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.fetch(DatastoreImpl.java:353) ~[google-cloud-datastore-1.105.0.jar:1.105.0] at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.datastore.core.DatastoreTemplate.findAllById(DatastoreTemplate.java:249)
```

**One  thing  i  noticed is  that  when  the  application  start  it  uses  default  compute  engine  credentials  to  authenticate**

I  am  not  sure  on  how  to  fix  this , searched  for  few  solutions  and  came  to  know  that  we  need  to  add  GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env  variable  in  deployment.yaml

```
spec:
 containers:
 - name: app
   image: eu.gcr.io/google_project_id/springapplication:v1
   volumeMounts:
   - name: google-cloud-key
     mountPath: /var/secrets/google
   env:
   - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
     value: /var/secrets/google/credentials.json
   ports:
   - name: http-server
     containerPort: 8080
 volumes:
 - name: google-cloud-key
   secret:
     secretName: app-key
```

Is this  the  right  way, since  the  credentials  file  is  a  confidential  one  where  we  store  it ideally(I  am  using  Jenkins  to  deploy  apps)

Someone  please  guide  me  on  this.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem at node level permission. When you create your cluster, and your node pool, you can choose the security of your node. And you can explicitly allow or deny the access to some API, such as Datastore. And by default Datastore is disabled.

[image]

You can check this in the Compute Engine that compose your GKE cluster:

[image]

If you don't want to delete your Cluster, you need to create a new node pool, to migrate your pod and to remove the old node pool.

---

Side remark. Don't you Service account key files. I recommend you to use [workload identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity) for a better security

Comment: Hi  all  the  nodes  have  full  access  to  gcloud  apis...any  more  suggestions?

Comment: Is it work locally? If it's not the compute engine scope, it's the credentials.

Comment: yz...the  issue  is  when  app  starts  it  is  using  default  compute  engine  credentials  and  not  the  credentials  of  the  compute  engine  service  account  of  nodes.When  i  pass  credentials  as  base  64  string  within  code  using **spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.encoded-key**  in  app.properties it  is  wrking and  datastore  issue  is  resolved , but  this  is  not  good solution  at  all  so  can  you  suggest  a  better  solution